# Solving (stiff) ODE's over a restricted domian

Tags: ode, numerical-integration

Assume I have a set of ordinary-differential-equations (ODEs) called *f*.
Further assume that *f* is only defined over a subspace *P* of *R^n*. **The ODEs *f* are defined in such a way that any initial point chosen from *P* will remain in *P* when integrated.**

**How do I enforce that this remains "true" for the numerical solution.** "True" because I would also be satisfied with a solution that would recover (quickly) from such an incident.

Typically solvers can not guarantee that a solution remains in a certain domain.
This is particularly problematic if *f* is stiff.

Based on the comment of Peter Meisrimel:
There exists certain integration methods notably the [Patanka-scheme](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10236-005-0001-x.pdf) that solve this problem for a specific setting.
However, I am looking for a (if possible) general approach.

---

To give an simple **example**, we can take a look at the Lotka-Voltera equations:

[image]

The solution looks something like this:
[image]

The equations is only defined for *x*,*y* being positive or zero.
However, if the problem is more complicated and stiff it can easily happen that during the integration of this ODE the solution reaches a negative value due to numerical errors.

How can I "recover" the solution if this happens or even avoid it in a general case?

I can of course always reduce the step size in the hope that this avoids the problem, but this is not necessarily feasible.

Comment: Given a non-negative solution, a negative solution is an accuracy problem and can certainly be fixed by higher accuracy. This might come in the form of rejecting steps and possibly repeating them with smaller stepsizes. I am not sure if this is a common feature in odesolvers. Other than that there are also positvity preserving schemes, one class I know about are "Patankar-Runge-Kutta" schemes, which preserve both positivity and are conservative as well.

Comment: I am not sure how you imagine a more "general solution" to look like. You do a step, you get a negative result, anything happening after that will be highly unphysical, there is no likely recovery, unless the hope that two "wrongs" will magically result in a "right". So you want to prevent negative results in the first place. So, a) you employ a specialized solver to preserve an extra property (there might be others), at a cost, or  b) increase accuracy.

Comment: I expected or better hoped for an algorithm that given a generic integration scheme and the domain of definition of the ODE ensures that its output remains in said domain for all times or if not recovers sufficiently quickly.
I.e.: 
1) a modification to the ODEs of the form: if current step not in domain, apply modified ODE to recover valid solution
2) a efficient step rejection, step size correction method that is unconditionally "stable".
Is this simply a hard problem in general or why isn't there something like this? I assumed that this is something that is needed in many applications.

Comment: 1. This would be adding a algebraic constraint, making it a differential algebraic equation. However, I do not know how to handle inequalities there. Maybe this is possible. 2. Sundials has some notes on how it handles this: https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/usage-notes

Comment: Thank you very much for you comments. I will look into it!